# Get Related ParseUser From a ParseRelation for Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have 2 classes

> 1. User
> 2. StockProduct

StockProduct has a relation column **sold_by** for User.

[image]

I am trying to retrieve **sold_by**  for the corresponding **StockProduct** but, it's returning **0 objects** for the following code.

```
 /**
 * GET SELLER FOR CURRENT PRODUCT
 * current_stock_object: ParseObject for StockProduct 
 */

 ParseRelation getSellerRelation = current_stock_object.getRelation("sold_by");
 ParseQuery getSeller = getSellerRelation.getQuery();

 getSeller.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

   @Override
   public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
       if (e!=null){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       Log.d("SIZE", Integer.toString(users.size()));
   }
});
```

Output:
[image]

I successfully retrieve the relation via Parse DataBrowser.

[image]

**SIDE NOTE**

```
 /**
 * GET PRICE FOR CURRENT PRODUCT
 */

 ParseRelation<ParseObject> getPriceRelation = current_stock_object.getRelation("prices");
 ParseQuery getPrice = getPriceRelation.getQuery();
 getPrice.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject>prices, ParseException e) {
        Log.d("PRICE SIZE", Integer.toString(prices.size()));
        System.out.println(prices.get(0).get("costPrice"));
    }
});
```

[image]
Works perfectly fine, leaving me with the thought that, getting ParseUser requires a different approach.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I would try:

```
ParseRelation<ParseUser> getSellerRelation = current_stock_object.getRelation("sold_by");
getSellerRelation.getQuery().findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

   @Override
   public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
       if (e!=null){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       Log.d("SIZE", Integer.toString(users.size()));
   }
});
```

All I added was an explicit type to the ParseRelation (in this case ParseUser). The documentation uses exactly this syntax, so I'm not sure why this wouldn't work for fetching the Relation.. maybe your "current_stock_object" needs to be fetched, or the "current_stock_object" is not the one you are looking at in the Parse console. Use the debugger and check the fields of your "current_stock_object" and ensure the objectId matches the one you are looking at in the console. Again, the object could be stale may need a fetch

**Side note:** (unrelated possibly)

Be sure to only use ParseRelation for a many-to-many relationship, otherwise just store the ParseObjects directly as a field. In this case, you have a StockProduct with a relation to _User table. If it makes sense in your application that a StockProduct can have multiple sellers, stick with the ParseRelation. If it was actually intended that a StockProduct may only have one unique seller, switch to not using a ParseRelation

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I tried the `ParseRelation<ParseUser> getSellerRelation = current_stock_object.getRelation("sold_by");` , but it hasn't changed the result. it's still **0 objects**.

Comment: `System.out.println(current_stock_object.getObjectId());` gives the correct objectId 
`01-21 01:21:28.166 30790-30790/com.localbay.anuragsingh I/System.out: xDq7vGyO8r`

Comment: Try just casting the relation to be a ParseRelation<ParseObject>. ParseUser is a subclass of ParseObject anyways, so it should work just fine..

Comment: Have tried that already, I am able to retrieve an object via Relation from a different class, through the same approach. It doesn't seem to work for ParseUser. Updated the question depicting the above scenario. Thanks.

Comment: no problem! glad I could help, I figured it would be easier and makes more sense

Comment: current_`stock.getParseUser("sold_by")` is returning NULL, is it because I used <ParseObject> while retrieving the StockProduct, which has the pointer column to ParseUser.

 `ParseQuery<ParseObject> getStockDetails = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("StockProduct");`

Comment: Anurag: Switch from parse, as today only Fb has announced that it would be winding their services, 

see "We have a difficult announcement to make. Beginning today we're winding down the Parse service, and Parse will be fully retired after a year-long period ending on January 28, 2017. We're proud that we've been able to help so many of you build great mobile apps, but we need to focus our resources elsewhere."